# Windows Desktop Duplication API Equivalent IOS

Tags: c++, windows, macos, equivalent

I'm looking for an equivalent of Windows Desktop Duplication API on MacOS.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx

The goal of the Windows API is to detect when Pixel change on Desktop and only update the screen when it is the case.

Do MacOS have the equivalent of this API ? Or does anyone know any tools or API that can do the same behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What you are looking for is `CGDisplayStream`:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgdisplaystream

Comment: Thanks ! That was exactly what I was looking for !